# scala.js Есть ли аналог метода fetch?

Tags: ajax, scala, scala.js

Я использую `scala.js` и `scala.js-react` поверх него. Для того, чтоб послать `ajax` запрос, пишу примерно следующее:

```
def send(e: ReactEventFromInput) = Callback{
  val v = e.currentTarget.value
  val formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("myVar", v)

  val xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
  xhr.onreadystatechange = (e: org.scalajs.dom.Event) => {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        println("Sended!")
      } else {
        println("Error!")
      }
    }
  }

  xhr.open("POST", "/my-api-route", true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHTTPRequest")
  xhr.send(formData)
}
```

Этот код работает. но он очень длинный.

Есть ли в `scala.js` аналог метода [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) из `JavaScript`? Или что-то другое, что способно сократить эту портянку?

Comment: Не это? https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/experimental/Fetch.scala

Comment: Отталкивает тем, что в папке `experimental` лежит )

Comment: По ссылке MDN - написано что он эксперементальный :)

Comment: Там немного не о том. На mdn речь идет о том, что `fetch` поддерживается еще не всеми браузерами, но он стандартизирован. А вот что тут имеется ввиду - не понятно. По-хорошему, используя `fetch` в `js`, я всегда докручиваю полифил. Докручивает ли его `scala.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл объект `Ajax`. Его способ использования напоминает fetch. Так-же он использует футуры, так что можно закрыть глаза и представить, что это промисы :)

```
def send(e: ReactEventFromInput) = Callback{
    val v = e.currentTarget.value
    val formData = new FormData
    formData.append("myVar", v)

    Ajax.post("/my-api-route", formData) map (r =>
      println("Sended!")
    ) onFailure {
      case dom.ext.AjaxException(r) => println("Error:" + r.response)
    }
}
```